# Set v-select option default from a method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following v-select:

```
 <v-select v-model="selectState" class="select-field my-0 py-0"
      :items="itemState"
      item-value="id"
      item-text="paymentState"            
      label="Payment State"
      @change="changedState()"
      clearable>
  </v-select>
```

In the data I have it initialized in the following way:

```
selectState: {
  id: '1',
  state: 'Registered'
},
itemState: [
  {id: '1', paymentState: 'Registered'},
  {id: '2', paymentState: 'Confirmed'},
  {id: '3', paymentState: 'Refused'},
],
```

Now in the method when pressing a button, I want the v-select to return me to the initial state, if for example I have already selected another option:

```
clearFilters(){
  let me = this;
  me.selectState //here the logic to set a default state 'Registered'
},
```

I have dealt with, but don't works:

```
me.selectState.itemState.paymentState = 'Registered';
```

Answer (score 1):

your code is wierd.
the selectState has no itemState property. and itemState is an array.
so you can try this:

```
 this.selectState = this.itemState[0];
```